# Nullable object must have a value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

When I'm trying show the data from database, I get the error. Type of data is integer and it's nullable. I've try this code :

```
Me.txtVoucher.Text = IIf(BNK.Voucher.HasValue, BNK.Voucher.Value, "")
```

but when the data from database is null I got the error :

> Nullable object must have a value.

Can Anyone help me? Thank's for all your help

Comment: Try `If(BNK.Voucher.HasValue, BNK.Voucher, "")` instead.

Comment: it's still getting error

Comment: So is the error when you're setting your object values or when you want to use them, or both?

Comment: the error is when I want to use them, when in database have a value, there's nothing error, but when the value is null, it's getting the error. *sorry for really late respond